# Pod restarting continuously impact

Tags: kubernetes

I had an argument with my colleague about what is wrong if we used only readiness probe for every issue (database failure, external service loading after startup, ...)

Is there some impact with restarting just one pod continuously till the issue is fixed ?

the same question for multiple pods restarting continuously at the same times

Comment: You know that you can tweak the [container restart poilcy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#restart-policy), right?. It does not try to restart the pods as soon as they fail. "After containers in a Pod exit, the kubelet restarts them with an exponential back-off delay (10s, 20s, 40s, …), that is capped at five minutes".

Comment: Kubernetes will (eventually) try to restart the failed pods every 5 minutes. How big of an impact do you believe that will have on your system? You can also use `restartPolicy: Never` and after a pod fails, it won't be restarted automatically.

Answer (score 0):

To Deploy with **restartPolicy: never** and then use [kubectl patch](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/manage-deployment/#kubectl-patch) to modify the restart policy of that deployment.

To avoid continuous restart attempt of failing pod there is one open [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/49466).